# Checking if a URL contains all elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm working on a project where I want to produce a list of all the Ebay item URLs that match a given set of keywords and a set price. So far, I've managed to make it work by first creating a URL in the format EBay requires using the user's input keywords and price, and then returning only the URLs from that page that include /itm/ as these will be the item URLs. However, I run into a problem when the keywords become too specific. When Ebay turns up less than 10 results for a given search, it will also provide you with some links to 'related products' that match some but not all of your keywords. I don't want to return the links to these related products. I've tried to take this into account by splitting the input user keywords into a list and then putting an If statement where the URL has to contain all the elements in this list, but that didn't work, and I get this error message: TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not bool.

See my code below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cherrypy

user_keyword = input("What would you like to search for? ")

print(user_keyword)


keywords_url = user_keyword.replace(' ', '%20')


user_price = input("What is your maximum price? ")

url_part1 = 'http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw='
url_part2 = '&_dcat=55793&rt=nc&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo&_udhi='

url = (url_part1 + keywords_url + url_part2 + user_price)


r= requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        if '/itm/' in link['href']: #Makes sure we only get actual item links
          if all(user_keyword.split(' ')) in link['href']: 
              print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python keyword `all` is basically and:ing a list (or similar) of logical values. Thus, you must first test for each word in `user_keyword` individually and then use `all` on the final result:

`if all(word in link['href'] for word in user_keyword.split(' ')):`

This piece of code uses list comprehension to generate a list (or rather a generator, since there are no list markers []) of boolean values, where all the values are `True` if the link contains all the user keywords.